# "There was a problem while parsing the package" when i am trying to install my APP,

Tags: react-native, installation, parse-error

following these steps :

Step 2:
Clean gradle setup
In android dir
./gradlew clean

Step 3:
In app root directory
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/

Step 4:
In android dir
./gradlew assembleRelease

Comment: Please update your question with the error getting after this

Comment: same issue let me know if anything worked for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74502338/parsing-the-package-issue-in-react-native